# Transition between two viewcontroller XAMARIN.IOS

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios

i am trying to create a transaction between two view controllers on xamarin.ios (i am not using the navigation controllers but the viewcontrollers), i would like that when the swipe gesture is in progress it appears under the view controller that moves another side viewcontroller (the target one) I'm trying to emulate the classic "go back" gesture of ios present both on the system itself and on whatsapp. I had already posted and I had partially solved, managing the scrolling animation, but for the second view controller nothing to do :(

[image]

my code...

```
private void InteractiveTransitionRecognizerActionWithoutIndex(UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer sender, UIView View, string x)
                {
                    
                    //Contiene un valore numerico che varia in base allo stato della gesture
                    var percento = sender.TranslationInView(View).X * 100 / sender.View.Bounds.Size.Width;
                    var storyboard = UIStoryboard.FromName("Main", null);
                   // var viewController = storyboard.InstantiateViewController(x);
            
                    

                    //Quando la gesture rileva una variazione
                    if (sender.State == UIGestureRecognizerState.Changed)
                    {
                        var minTransform = CGAffineTransform.MakeTranslation(sender.TranslationInView(View).X, 0); //*2 = piu rapido
                        var maxTransform = CGAffineTransform.MakeTranslation(sender.TranslationInView(View).X, 0);

                        View.Transform = true ? minTransform : maxTransform;


                        UIView.Animate(0.1, 0, UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseInOut,
                            () =>
                            {
                                View.Transform = true ? maxTransform : minTransform;

                                //???
                                
                                
                            },
                            null
                        );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **storyboards** and familiar with segues. To define a custom transition animation you will have to configure your segue as follows:

[image]

Then in the first view controller you can override the `PrepareForSegue` method:

```
public override void PrepareForSegue(UIStoryboardSegue segue, NSObject sender)
{
    base.PrepareForSegue(segue, sender);

    var destinationVC = segue.DestinationViewController as SecondViewController;
    destinationVC.Callee = this;
    destinationVC.TransitioningDelegate = new CustomTransitioningDelegate(sender as UIView);
    destinationVC.ModalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.Custom;
}
```

```
public class CustomTransitioningDelegate: UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate
{
    readonly UIView _animationOrigin;

    public CustomTransitioningDelegate(UIView animationOrigin)
    {
        _animationOrigin = animationOrigin;
    }

    public override IUIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning GetAnimationControllerForPresentedController(UIViewController presented, UIViewController presenting, UIViewController source)
    {
        var customTransition = new GrowTransitionAnimator(_animationOrigin);
        return customTransition;
    }
}
```

The animations are defined in a class that inherit from **UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning**.

```
public class GrowTransitionAnimator : UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning
{
    readonly UIView _animationOrigin;

    public GrowTransitionAnimator(UIView animationOrigin)
    {
        _animationOrigin = animationOrigin;
    }

    public override async void AnimateTransition(IUIViewControllerContextTransitioning transitionContext)
    {
        // The animation here
    }

    public override double TransitionDuration(IUIViewControllerContextTransitioning transitionContext)
    {
        return 0.3;
    }
}
```

Comment: the "segue" panel is not present in my storyboard.. 
what type of controller are you using?

Comment: You could share your sample so that I can test it on my side directly .